# ie 32kb limit to data uri

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

Long story short, I have an image that is stored as a string in a database. I am then displaying the image in a jcarousellite carousel. When the user clicks the image, it pops up in lightbox. When the image is displayed in the carousel, it renders the whole image perfectly (the image is sized much smaller in the carousel). When the image is clicked, it only renders the top 10(ish) pixels of the image in IE. I know that there is a 32kb limit to the IE and data URIs. Is there a way to get around this and be able to display the image correctly?

If you need any source code, I am more than happy to provide some.

Thanks,
ZS

EDIT

```
var oDataQuery = /*Query*/
var carouselul = $("#carousel-ul");
var parentBody = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var outterDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
// Execute the OData query for the images
    $.getJSON(oDataQuery, function (data) {
        var results = data.d.results;

        // Add the results to the carousel ul            
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var noteId = results[i].AnnotationId;
            var noteSubject = results[i].Subject;

            var src = "data:" + results[i].MimeType + ";base64," + results[i].DocumentBody;

            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var ahref = document.createElement('a');
            ahref.href = '#';
            ahref.addEventListener('click', function () { return false; });
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = src;
            img.width = '100';
            img.height = '100';
            img.style.border = '1px solid';
            img.style.margin = '1px';
            img.addEventListener('click', function() { $("#img" + noteId, window.parent.document).trigger('click'); });

            ahref.appendChild(img);
            li.appendChild(ahref);

            carouselul.append(li);

            var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            innerDiv.id = "div" + noteId;

            var img2 = "<a href='" + src + "' data-title='" + noteSubject + "' id='" + noteId + "' data-lightbox='images'><img id='img" + noteId + "' src='";
            img2 += src;
            img2 += "' width='100' height='100' style='border: 1px solid; margin: 1px; visibility: hidden' alt='";
            img2 += noteSubject + "' /></a>";

            innerDiv.innerHTML = img2;

            outterDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

            tempID = "img" + noteId;
        }

        var oHead = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
        cssNode.type = 'text/css';
        cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
        cssNode.href = '/{635457923130000051}/WebResources/ta_lightbox';
        oHead.appendChild(cssNode);

        parentBody.appendChild(outterDiv);

        // Wire-up jCarouselLite to the carousel div            
        $("#carousel").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: "#next",
            btnPrev: "#prev",
            circular: false
        });
```

I know the code looks kinda crazy but I am rendering the image in an iframe and then it needs to display the lightbox outside of the iframe. (it is all on the same server so I know this all works just fine, it is just the image only renders only the top 10(ish) pixels.

Comment: Is the full size image's data uri being generated by the client or is it being sent by the server? Also, how far back in IE do you need to support? (Please say IE10+ to make the world a better place)

Comment: It is being generated on the client side. I only need to support 10+ (thank god)

Comment: Please supply the code generating it; to avoid this issue, you'll need to go down the _Blob_ and `URL.createObjectURL` path (if you want `<img>`) or use a `<canvas>`

Comment: Okay this looks like you're sending the _Base64_ from the server; you'll need to do a _Base64_ to _Blob_ conversion (possible in _JavaScript_, many examples online) and store _Blobs_ in your _JavaScript_ instead

Comment: I edited the post so it should be more clear. I am sorry if the code is sloppy... I am not a web developer so this is all newer to me.

Comment: Have you considered rending the images on the server side with something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your *base64* to *bytes* and use them to create a *Blob*, from which you can generate an *object URL* which works differently to a *data URL*, so you've avoided the size limit of *URLs*

(I've re-factored a bit of your code, this to replace your `for` loop, I've ignored the rest)

```
function makeDivTemplate() { // helper to simplify loop
    var div = document.createElementById('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="" data-title="" data-lightbox="images"><img src="" width="100" height="100" style="border: 1px solid; margin: 1px; visibility: hidden" alt="">';
    return div;
}

function makeLiTemplate() { // helper to simplify loop
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        a = document.createElement('a'),
        img = document.createElement('img');
    a.href = '#';
    img.width = '100';
    img.height = '100';
    img.style.border = '1px solid';
    img.style.margin = '1px';
    a.appendChild(img);
    li.appendChild(a);
    return li;
}

var results = data.d.results;
var innerDivTemplate = makeDivTemplate(); // cloneNode will be faster than fn
var liTemplate = makeLiTemplate();

// Add the results to the carousel ul
var i, div, e, li, id, subject, blob, src; // var in a loop gets hoisted anyway
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    id = results[i].AnnotationId;
    subject = results[i].Subject;
    blob = new Blob( // create Blob
        [base64DecToArr(results[i].DocumentBody)], // base64 to bytes
        {type: results[i].MimeType}
    );
    src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // <li> tree
    li = liTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    e = li; // <li>
    e = e.firstChild; // <a>
    e.addEventListener('click', function () { return false; });
    e = e.firstChild; // <img>
    e.setAttribute('src', src);
    e.addEventListener('click', function() { $("#img" + id, window.parent.document).trigger('click'); });

    carouselul.append(li);

    // <div> tree
    div = innerDivTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    e = div; // <div>
    e.setAttribute('id', 'div' + id);
    e = e.firstChild; // <a>
    e.setAttribute('src', src);
    e.setAttribute('data-title', subject);
    e.setAttribute('id', id);
    e = e.firstChild; // <img>
    e.setAttribute('src', src);
    e.setAttribute('alt', subject);
    e.setAttribute('id', 'img' + id);

    outterDiv.appendChild(div);
}
blob = null;
```

And also include the following two functions from [**the MDN page on *Base64***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_.232_.E2.80.93_rewriting_atob()_and_btoa()_using_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8)

```
function b64ToUint6 (nChr) {
  return nChr > 64 && nChr < 91 ?
      nChr - 65
    : nChr > 96 && nChr < 123 ?
      nChr - 71
    : nChr > 47 && nChr < 58 ?
      nChr + 4
    : nChr === 43 ?
      62
    : nChr === 47 ?
      63
    :
      0;
}

function base64DecToArr (sBase64, nBlocksSize) {
  var
    sB64Enc = sBase64.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g, ""), nInLen = sB64Enc.length,
    nOutLen = nBlocksSize ? Math.ceil((nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2) / nBlocksSize) * nBlocksSize : nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2, taBytes = new Uint8Array(nOutLen);

  for (var nMod3, nMod4, nUint24 = 0, nOutIdx = 0, nInIdx = 0; nInIdx < nInLen; nInIdx++) {
    nMod4 = nInIdx & 3;
    nUint24 |= b64ToUint6(sB64Enc.charCodeAt(nInIdx)) << 18 - 6 * nMod4;
    if (nMod4 === 3 || nInLen - nInIdx === 1) {
      for (nMod3 = 0; nMod3 < 3 && nOutIdx < nOutLen; nMod3++, nOutIdx++) {
        taBytes[nOutIdx] = nUint24 >>> (16 >>> nMod3 & 24) & 255;
      }
      nUint24 = 0;

    }
  }

  return taBytes;
}
```